# How can I modify the Activity Report to display phone number?

Tags: civireport, activities

I have built a report off of the Activity Report template and have been able to add all the columns I need EXCEPT target contact phone number. Email and many address fields are available in the "columns" tab but I do not see phone number there.

Is there anything I can do to expose this information?

(I thought about using a Constituent Report (Detail) instead, because phone is available there--but I want to filter by activity type and include custom fields on my activities.)

Comment: Hey Lisa!  I gave an answer below - but if you want to work through this together, contact me privately via e-mail.

Comment: Thanks so much, Jon! I will check this out and reach out if nec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Lola Slade's excellent CiviCon presentations on this topic:  [2015 session](https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/civicrm-custom-reports-101) (download the PDF on this page); [2015 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlGovqePUiw&list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs&index=5), and the [CiviCon 2012](http://sf2012.civicrm.org/sites/default/files/slides/CiviCRM%20Reports-Customize%20and%20Extend.pdf) slideshow.